PySide6 GUI displays differently on different computers
I have a GUI application built in PySide6. Mostly it works fine, but a specific part of it displays differently on different machines: specifically, the text color is white on one machine, but black (as it should be) on every other machine I have tested on. Comparison below:
Working:

Not working

Same code, same python version, same library versions. I have completely uninstalled python, and reinstalled all packages from scratch, to no effect.
The major difference between the test setups is the screen resolution, but resetting the screen resolutions to match across different machines does not change anything. I have also added
QGuiApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
QGuiApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps)

before instantiating anything per some advice elsewhere about standardizing resolutions, but this also has no visible effect.
I am hoping that someone recognizes a known issue from the visual difference. Any ideas?

Just a wild guess, but maybe for some reason (dark mode, theming, etc.), the default text color is different on the one machine? You might want to have a look at this question to get the default text color for confirmation. Or am I misunderstanding your question, and you already know this?

good suggestion, thank you!

This seems almost certainly related to QPalette, possibly caused by system configuration (including user selected colors). Icons seem to be affected too, how are they created? Are they possibly generated using fontawesome or similar/related packages?

Yes - setting the font color for the app via app.setStyleSheet("QWidget { color: black; }") fixes the font issues but not the icon issues. Points to a style sheet issue in the creation of the whole widget, so I will have to go digging. But this has already been super helpful in narrowing it down, thank you @simon

@musicamante where would I go to figure out the relevant system config?

@KBriggs Don't use that, setting stylesheet properties for all widgets is never a good idea. Instead, check the QPalette documentation, especially the ButtonText role. It's quite likely that you just need to explicitly set the color for the palette and apply the palette to the application,.

@KBriggs How could I know? We don't even know what OS is that...

@musicamante yes, I will not use that in prod, I am just using it to validate the idea. I am using Win11 - new to PySide6, was not sure if this was a package setting or a system setting - sorry for the silly question!

As said, check the QPalette documentation. The style is not required to comply with the palette, as it's just a "suggestion". In any case: 1. the palette is based on the system palette, check the appearance configuration on Windows' control panel; 2. without knowing how those icons are generated, we cannot tell you more; 3. you should be very careful in explicitly setting colors, especially application wide: if you specify the foreground, then you must specify the background, then other colors too, so that they match others, otherwise you'd have problems for users with different settings.

@KBriggs Generally speaking, unless you're willing to specify the whole palette (and you are completely sure that all widgets will respect that), you should avoid doing it to begin with: if the user has a faulty configuration with colors that don't offer appropriate contrast, that's their problem, not yours.

Fair enough, thank you for the advice!

@musicamante the issue was windows dark mode. That caused fonts to default to white, but a few of the widgets had explicitly set white backgrounds. Lesson learned... no more explicit style sheets for me.
